# SQL syntax error on INSERT with mysql using array of escaped req.body values

Tags: mysql, node.js, insert, escaping

Thank you in advance for taking a look at this question! So, I am attempting to INSERT a row of data into a table named raw_base.

Here is the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mysql = require('mysql');

// Import MySQL Options
const options = require('../db_options');

const connection = mysql.createConnection(options);

router.post('/raw', (req, res) => {
    let data = [
        `${connection.escape(req.body[0].opened)}`,
        `${connection.escape(req.body[0].funding_source)}`,
        `${connection.escape(req.body[0].replace_existing_device)}`,
        `${connection.escape(req.body[0].project)}`,
        `${connection.escape(req.body[0].department)}`,
        `${connection.escape(req.body[0].ritm_number)}`,
        `${connection.escape(req.body[0].item)}`,
        `${connection.escape(req.body[0].category)}`,
        `${connection.escape(req.body[0].quantity)}`,
        `${connection.escape(req.body[0].price)}`,
        `${connection.escape(req.body[0].closed)}`
    ];

    connection.query('INSERT INTO `raw_base` (`opened`, `funding_source`, `replace_existing_device`, `project`, `department`, `ritm_number`, `item`, `category`, `quantity`, `price`, `closed`) VALUES ?', [data], (error, results, fields) => {
                if (error) throw error;
                console.log(results);
            });
```

As such, I am receiving the following error:

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\'2018-07-26 13:34:33\'', '127548298', '0', '0', '\'Psychiatry Admin-Central\'', '' at line 1

If; however, I do not escape the values in the data array and add single quotes around the values in the sql INSERT query it works fine (like this):

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO `raw_base` (`opened`, `funding_source`, `replace_existing_device`, `project`, `department`, `ritm_number`, `item`, `category`, `quantity`, `price`, `closed`) VALUES ('
    + '\'' + req.body[0].opened + '\', '
    + '\'' + req.body[0].funding_source + '\', '
    + '\'' + req.body[0].replace_existing_device + '\', '
    + '\'' + req.body[0].project + '\', '
    + '\'' + req.body[0].department + '\', '
    + '\'' + req.body[0].ritm_number + '\', '
    + '\'' + req.body[0].item + '\', '
    + '\'' + req.body[0].category + '\', '
    + '\'' + req.body[0].quantity + '\', '
    + '\'' + req.body[0].price + '\', '
    + '\'' + req.body[0].closed + '\')'
    , (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(results);
    });
```

I have also attempted to add single quotes around around each value in the data array with no luck.  I assume this is a simple syntactical issue, but I can't seem to place my finger on exactly where I am going wrong.  Thanks again for helping out!

Here is are the values from the data array (from req.body[0]):

> [ '\'2018-07-26 13:34:33\'',
>     '127548298',
>     '0',
>     '0',
>     '\'Psychiatry Admin-Central\'',
>     '\'RITM0023102\'',
>     '\'HP USB Keyboard\'',
>     '\'Accessories\'',
>     '6',
>     '14',
>     '\'2018-08-22 12:51:40\'' ]

Comment: Your problem is messy data. You want something like `[ '2018-07-26 13:34:33', '275829', '0', '0', 'Psychiatry Admin-Central', ... ]`. But for some reason the data contains escaped strings, as in `'\'2018-07-26 13:34:33\''`. You need to fix that problem before using the data.

Comment: It is the connection.escape() method that is creating the escaped characters... not sure it would be good practice.  Thoughts?

Comment: `escape` can only work on what is already there. The problem isn't that `escape` is escaping single quotes; it is that you have literal single quotes *inside your strings*. Why, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the connection.escape()'s completely from the data array (in doing some more research it appears it is unnecessary to escape these values):

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mysql = require('mysql');

// Import MySQL Options
const options = require('../db_options');

const connection = mysql.createConnection(options);

router.post('/raw', (req, res) => {
    let data = [
        req.body[0].opened,
        req.body[0].funding_source,
        req.body[0].replace_existing_device,
        req.body[0].project,
        req.body[0].department,
        req.body[0].ritm_number,
        req.body[0].item,
        req.body[0].category,
        req.body[0].quantity,
        req.body[0].price,
        req.body[0].closed
    ];

    connection.query('INSERT INTO `raw_base` (`opened`, `funding_source`, `replace_existing_device`, `project`, `department`, `ritm_number`, `item`, `category`, `quantity`, `price`, `closed`) VALUES (?)', [data], (error, results, fields) => {
                if (error) throw error;
                console.log(results);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the ( ) around the ? in your query.
Try this

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mysql = require('mysql');

// Import MySQL Options
const options = require('../db_options');

const connection = mysql.createConnection(options);

router.post('/raw', (req, res) => {
    let data = [
        connection.escape(req.body[0].opened),
        connection.escape(req.body[0].funding_source),
        connection.escape(req.body[0].replace_existing_device),
        connection.escape(req.body[0].project),
        connection.escape(req.body[0].department),
        connection.escape(req.body[0].ritm_number),
        connection.escape(req.body[0].item),
        connection.escape(req.body[0].category),
        connection.escape(req.body[0].quantity),
        connection.escape(req.body[0].price),
        connection.escape(req.body[0].closed)
    ];

    connection.query('INSERT INTO `raw_base` (`opened`, `funding_source`, `replace_existing_device`, `project`, `department`, `ritm_number`, `item`, `category`, `quantity`, `price`, `closed`) VALUES (?)', [data], (error, results, fields) => {
                if (error) throw error;
                console.log(results);
            });
```

Edit: extracted the connection.escape from the Strings.

Comment: Thank you @KeeyPee, removing the interpolation from the items in the array was definitely good practice; however, it appears that the connection.escape() is adding the escaped single quotes that are causing my issue.  Anyone have any idea on how to avoid this?

Comment: @sivs Ah i forgot you dont need to do a connection.escape because it is doing it automatically in the prepared statement. Try the insert without your connection.escape